# Proving that the metric space $(\mathcal{H}(\mathbb{D}), d)$ is complete using Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, complete-spaces

Call the vector space of holomorphic functions on the unit disk $\mathcal{H}(\mathbb{D})$. Define for $f, g \in \mathcal{H}(\mathbb{D})$: $$d(f,g) = \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}2^{-k}\min\left(1, \sup_{|z|\leq1-\frac{1}{k}}|f(z)-g(z)|\right).$$ I think it's quite straightforward to prove that this defines a metric on $\mathcal{H}(\mathbb{D})$ (only my proof for the triangle inequality might be not entirely correct, but that another question in itself).

Now I want to prove that this metric space $(\mathcal{H}(\mathbb{D}), d)$ is complete. For this I first wanted to prove that a sequence $(f_n)_n$ in $\mathcal{H}(\mathbb{D})$ converges in $(\mathcal{H}(\mathbb{D}), d)$ if and only if it converges uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{D}$. I tried proving the first implication by noticing that since $\forall \epsilon > 0$ there exists a $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$ it holds that $d(f_n,f) < \epsilon$. Therefore the sum in $d(f_n,f)$ must be small in each term, so for the first few terms it must hold that $$\min\left(1, \sup_{|z|\leq1-\frac{1}{k}}|f(z)-g(z)|\right) = \sup_{|z|\leq1-\frac{1}{k}}|f(z)-g(z)|.$$ But does this hold? And how I proceed with the rest of the proof?

For the converse statement, it must hold in any compact subset $K$ of $\mathbb{D}$ that $\forall \epsilon > 0$ there exists a $N$ such that $\forall n \geq N$ $\textbf{and}$ $\forall z \in K$  it holds that $|f_n(z),f(z)| < \epsilon$. But I'm now confused on how to proceed with the proof because in $d(f,g)$ the supremum is taken over all $z \leq 1 - 1/k$, not just the ones in some compact set $K$.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one direction one can split the sum in two parts: One finite sum and a “small“ remainder:
$$d(f_n,f) \le  \sum^{N}_{k=1}2^{-k}\min\left(1, \sup_{|z|\leq1-\frac{1}{k}}|f_n(z)-f(z)|\right) + \frac{1}{2^N}
$$
for every positive integer $N$. If $f_n \to f$ uniformly on compact sets of $\Bbb D$ then, given $\epsilon > 0$, you can first choose $N$ so large that $1/2^N  < \epsilon/2$, and then $n > N$ so large such that all of the *finitely many* terms in the sum are $< \epsilon/(2 N )$. It follows that $d(f_n, f) \to 0$.

For the other direction, if $d(f_n, f) \to 0$ and $K \subset \Bbb D$ is compact then $K \subset \{ z : |z| < 1-1/k \}$ for some $k$, and
$$
2^{-k}\min\left(1, \sup_{|z|\leq1-\frac{1}{k}}|f_n(z)-f(z)|\right) \le d(f_n, f) \, .
$$
Given $0 < \epsilon < 1$, $d(f_n, f) < \epsilon/2^k$ for $n \ge n_0$ then implies
$$
\sup_{z \in K}|f_n(z)-f(z)| \le
\sup_{|z|\leq1-\frac{1}{k}}|f_n(z)-f(z)| < \epsilon
$$
so that $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $K$.

---

In order to prove that $(\mathcal{H}(\mathbb{D}), d)$ is complete one can proceed as follows: Let $(f_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence in $(\mathcal{H}(\mathbb{D}), d)$.

Similar as in the second part above it follows that for every compact set $K \subset \Bbb D$, $(f_n)$ restricted to $K$ is a Cauchy sequence with respect to the supremums norm. It is a standard argument to show that $(f_n)$ is uniformly convergent on $K$, and that the limit function $f$ is holomorphic.

It then follows from the first part above that $f_n \to f$ in $(\mathcal{H}(\mathbb{D}), d)$.

One can also demonstrate $d(f_n, f) \to 0$ directly: If $\epsilon > 0$ then for all $N$ and sufficiently large $n, m \ge n_0$
$$
\sum^{N}_{k=1}2^{-k}\min\left(1, \sup_{|z|\leq1-\frac{1}{k}}|f_n(z)-f_m(z)|\right) \le d(f_n, f_m) < \epsilon \, .
$$
Letting $m \to \infty$ first and then $N \to \infty$ it follows that $d(f_n, f) < \epsilon$ for $n \ge n_0$.

Comment: Great! Is it then possible to prove that for any Cauchy sequence in $\mathcal{H}(\mathbb{D})$ that it converges uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{D}$? Then we could use what we have just proven to conclude that $\mathcal{H}(\mathbb{D})$ is complete.

Comment: Of course I meant we can then prove that $(\mathcal{H}(\mathbb{D}), d)$ is complete

Comment: @Geigercounter: I have updated it again, I am not sure if the previous argument was correct.